# Extract from current position until end of file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pull all data from a text file from a specified line number until the end of a file. This is how I've tried:

```
def extract_values(f):
    line_offset = []
    offset = 0
    last_line_of_heading = False

    if not last_line_of_heading:
        for line in f:
            line_offset.append(offset)
            offset += len(line)
            if whatever_condition:
                last_line_of_heading = True

    f.seek(0)

    # non-functioning pseudocode follows
    data = f[offset:]  # read from current offset to end of file into this variable
```

There is actually a blank line between the header and the data I want, so ideally I could skip this also.

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Do you have to do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the line number in advance? If so,

```
def extract_values(f):
    line_number = # something
    data = f.readlines()[line_number:]
```

If not, and you need to determine the line number based on the content of the file itself,

```
def extract_values(f):
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if some_condition(line):
            data = lines[line_number:]
            break
```

This will not be ideal if your files are enormous (since the lines of the file are loaded into memory); in that case, you might want to do it in two passes, only storing the file data on the second pass.

Comment: I do not have enough rep to upvote but will mark this as accepted (it won't let me right now). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small python program, LastLines.py

```
import sys

def main():
    firstLine = int(sys.argv[1])
    lines = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()[firstLine:]
    for curLine in lines:
        print curLine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example input, test1.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Example usage:

```
python LastLines.py 2 < test1.txt
```

Example output:

```
c
d
```

This program assumes that the first line in a file is the 0th line.

Comment: What if he's on Windows?

Comment: @senshin I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate:`

```
f=open('your_file')
for i,x in enumerate(f):
    if i >= your_line:
        #do your stuff
```

here i will store line number starting from `0` and `x` will contain the line

using list comprehension

```
[ x for i,x in enumerate(f) if i >= your_line ]
```

will give you list of lines after specified line

using dictionary comprehension

```
{ i:x for i,x in enumerate(f) if i >= your_line }
```

this will give you line number as key and line as value, from specified line number.

Answer (score 0):

Your if clause is at the wrong position:

```
for line in f:
    if not last_line_of_heading:
```

Consider this code:

```
def extract_values(f):
    rows = []
    last_line_of_heading = False

    for line in f:
        if last_line_of_heading:
            rows.append(line)
        elif whatever_condition:
            last_line_of_heading = True
    # if you want a string instead of an array of lines:
    data = "\n".join(rows)
```